# Getting Vue warning when trying to do symantic binding in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and trying to test semantic binding. I have Vue.js in the same directory as my test page but I get a Vue warning of "Cannot find element: #growler". Am I doing this correct?

html

```
<head>
    <title>
        Growler
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="growler"></div>
    <h2> {{ appName }} </h2>
</body>
```

app.js

```
var growler = new Vue({
    el: '#growler',
    data: {
        appName: 'Growler'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML-markup is wrong. 
The closing `div` tag has to be after the `h2`, otherwise the variable appName will not be found.

```html
<div id="growler">
    <h2> {{ appName }} </h2>
</div>
```

The error *"Cannot find element: #growler"* probably appears, because you include `app.js` in the head. Either move it downwards before the closing `body` tag or add some `window.onload`-condition to it to make sure, the JS will be executed after rendering the inital page.

Comment: Thanks whereo. I should have seen that.

Answer (score 0):

`app.js` script must be below the application div

Also you must put the h2 tag inside the #glower div
Because the vue application `glower` working only inside #glower div

```
<div id="growler">
     <h2> {{ appName }} </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <title>
        Growler
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="growler">
        <h2> {{ appName }} </h2>
    </div>
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

There was a error in your HTML.